# Null Pointer Exception when sending persistent data via Volley

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I am sending information currently stored in SharedPreferences over to a remote mysql database using Volley. I am getting a NullPointer Exception when I call the addDataToDB() method. Tested to see if the values exists and they do exist (using Log print out). Unable to understand why I'm getting the null pointer exception.

Added the relevant codes below.

Method used to send information to remote server:

```
private void addDataToDB(){

    username = preferences.getString("username", null);
    firstname = preferences.getString("firstname", null);
    lastname = preferences.getString("lastname", null);
    Log.d("TAG", "addDataToDB: " + username + firstname + lastname); //Getting correct name print outs

    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //not reaching here
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    RegisterRequestAll registerRequestAll = new RegisterRequestAll(
            username, firstname, lastname, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    queue.add(registerRequestAll);
}
```

RegisterRequestAll Class:

```
class RegisterRequestAll extends StringRequest{
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    RegisterRequestAll(
            String username, String firstname, String lastname, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("firstname", firstname);
        params.put("lastname", lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

register.php:

```
<?php

    require("connect.php"); // working file which connects to database

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

     function registerUser() {
        global $connection, $username, $firstname, $lastname, $response;

        $sql = "UPDATE user SET firstname=?, lastname=? WHERE username=?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $firstname, $lastname, $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        } 
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($connection);
        $response["success"] = true;  
    }   

    registerUser();
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Exception:

```
[263] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:450)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:436)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Answer (score 1):

it usually happens when you post null String

```
params.put("username", username);
params.put("firstname", firstname);
params.put("lastname", lastname);
```

one (or more) of username and ... are null;

Comment: As mentioned above, tested on the print out and the values I am passing in exists.

Comment: it only can be you url or param